# Export data into CSV gives Network Error - Apache Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I ran sql query successfully with %sql in Apache Zeppellin - 0.6.2, with
[image: Download Button]

Download option i'm getting Network error.

[image: Download Failed]

EDIT 1:

Logs

[image: Screen1]

Comment: Hi. logs are saved in /logs Could you post error log also?

Comment: @1ambda ,i've updated answer & i'm getting IOException.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I am not sure you are using zeppelin on docker or not.  The error message means, you don't have enough disk space. If you are using linux (or MacOS) try `df -h` in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into the same thing. The problem is when you hit download button, they do not have a file stored on server. Rather you will be given a url constructed from the contents of the table. It looks like

`data:image/svg;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BFPK%2CaccountId%2CteamId%2CteamUrl%2Cemail%2CfirstNam`

So when you have too long of a result, the url gets longer and browser fails to handle this too long url. And you see that Network Error...

EDIT: This was the case when I was using JDBC connection.